Send json Success message while keep sending Email
ı have code something like below. I m trying to send emails with some limits, for example if i have 10 email accounts in 'to_emails[]' i have to wait 210 seconds for finis of loading page and after that json gives success message to console  but i want to send succes message before it and  Even users left page i want to keep sending emails.
   $to_emails = [];

    foreach ($_POST['Gpname'] as $group_name) {
        if ($group_name == "hs") {

            $query = "SELECT email FROM login";
            $result = $con->query($query);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $to_emails[] = $row['email'];
            }
        } elseif ($group_name == "BY" || $group_name == "MY") {

            $query = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE group_name = ?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $group_name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $to_emails[] = $row['email'];
            }
        } else {

            $query = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE name = ?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $group_name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $to_emails[] = $row['email'];
            }
        }
    }




}




$success = "success";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($success);



$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.net';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'it.example@example.com';
    $mail->Password = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->setFrom('it.example@example.com', 'IT example');


    $limit = 120;

    $total_sent = 0;

    foreach ($to_emails as $email) {
        $mail->addAddress($email);

        $subject = "example";
        $message = "";
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;

        $mail->send();


        $mail->clearAddresses();

 


        if ($total_sent == $limit || $total_sent == count($to_emails)) {
            break;
        }
    

         $total_sent++;


        $interval = 21;
        sleep($interval);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "E-posta gönderme hatası: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}



continue processing php after sending http response

Read the advice in the PHPMailer mailing list docs, in particular about using a local mail server to act as a relay. Going that way, I would expect sending 10 messages should take well under a second.
